# Can the ffmpeg `loudnorm` extension be used to guarantee a maximum volume in an audio file?

Tags: volume, loudness, gain, ffmpeg

I'm looking at a way to ensure an audio file doesn't ever get too loud, but I do not want to change the samples if it is under a given threshold.

For example, I would like the file to have a maximum of -24dB. Anything in the file which is between -70dB and -24dB should not be changed.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the `loudnorm` extension of ffmpeg?

The following works if the input is over -24dB, but when it is under, it will increase the volume:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -vn -af loudnorm=I=-24 -ar 44.1k output.mp3
```

I'd like a way to decrease the volume only in areas where the input file is too loud.

Comment: Sounds like you want alimiter. See http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alimiter

Comment: @Gyan, I'll have to test that... Only I don't really see a way to specify the threshold in dB.

Comment: Add dB suffix e.g. `limit=-30dB`